# upload files directly from local folder, using browser

Tags: java, php, jquery, file-upload, ftp

i have to upload large number of files to server, directly from my pc, using only web browser.

which is best way to achieve that?

do i need some java applet, or is it possible to achieve woth php/jquery?

will it be unsecure if i try with php script that works with ftp connection?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's various ready-made plugins on doing file upload on jquery.

Doing this kind of uploading hacks is not an enjoyable experience, so people enjoy using ready-made solutions.

Here's few:

- [Ajax File Upload Plugin](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/)
- [Multiple File Upload Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/)
- [jQuery forms plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)  this posts your files through an iframe to get the effect :

you can also try [this](https://github.com/drogus/jquery-upload-progress)

You can search more from jquery's plugin -site.

Answer (score -1):

If your only web browser is mozilla firefox, then try fireftp addon plugin, it works similarly as normal FTP app.